# Exception. File is being used by another process (IMAGE)

Tags: c#, image, exception

I'm opening an Image, then i try to delete it but the following it's trown "C# exception. File is being used by another process"

I set the Picturebox to null.

```
pictureBox1.Image = null;
```

But the problem still continues.

```
//File.Delete(Application.StartupPath + @"\Recursos\Fotos\Tragos\" + nombre + ".jpg");//
```

Comment: So, what part of that don't you understand? The file is still being  used by some process. Maybe it's even _your_ process? How did you load the image? What other processing did you perform on the image?

Comment: BTW, setting things to null isn't really useful, as it was in the COM/VB6 days.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you load the image with file dialog. "Else you need to edit the code to use your way to open the file"
"Or provide more info or /and code"

After you selected the image use a file stream.
He will open the image , read it and then close it. " So it will not be in use"
I have put the OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog(); outside the button so i can get the info also in the delete button.

Then it works perfect.

```
   OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dlg.ShowDialog();
        if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            System.IO.FileStream LoadFile = default(System.IO.FileStream);
            LoadFile = new System.IO.FileStream(dlg.FileName, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);
            pictureBox1.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(LoadFile);
            LoadFile.Close();
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DialogResult Sure = MessageBox.Show("Are you Sure ?", "Delete Image", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        if (Sure == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = null;
            File.Delete(dlg.FileName);
        }
    }
```